# Magento admin section

Tags: magento

Hai

In my magneto project, admin side invoices, I want to display the product name, sku and 
manufactures, is it possible???

I know that when clicking View Link I can show, but I want to show the details in the table in the invoices page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best place to start is:

/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/tempalte/sales/order/invoice/view/

Everything within the /app/design/adminhtml/ is where you'll want to go to edit any available templates for the backend.

Remember that Magento is full of magic methods.  So, often times if you want to output a particular attribute, simply call something like: echo $_item->getManufacturer();

Hope that helps.